# What is the colors handle from WordPress core for and why does it not have a path?

Tags: wp-enqueue-style

Looping through `$wp_styles->registered`, the handle `colors` is outputted with a `$wp_style->src` of `1`. Searching through WordPress core, it isn't immediately clear what it's for.

The code is:

```
 global $wp_styles;
    $wp_styles  = wp_styles();
    foreach ( $wp_styles->registered as $wp_style ) {
      echo $wp_style->handle . " | " . $wp_style->src . "<br>";
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `colors` handle is for the "Admin Color Scheme" stylesheet (see the Users → Profile page at `wp-admin/profile.php`) and it's registered via [`wp_default_styles()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_default_styles/), like so:

( `$styles` is an instance of the [`WP_Styles` class](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_styles/) which extends the [`WP_Dependencies` class](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_dependencies/) which has an `add()` method where the second parameter is the stylesheet path )

```php
// Register a stylesheet for the selected admin color scheme.
$styles->add( 'colors', true, array( 'wp-admin', 'buttons' ) );
```

So the `$wp_style->src` (or `src` value for the `colors` style) is a boolean `true`, but because your code echo it, then [PHP converts it to the string "1"](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.casting) and that's why `$wp_style->src` in your code outputted a `1`. If you did `var_dump( $wp_style->src );`, then you would have noticed that it's a boolean.

And the reason the stylesheet's path or URL is not defined when it's registered, is because it will be set/determined dynamically via [`wp_style_loader_src()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_style_loader_src/), which is hooked on [`style_loader_src`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/style_loader_src/).

So for example, if I selected the "Sunrise" color scheme, then the above function might return a URL like `https://example.com/wp-admin/css/colors/sunrise/colors.min.css` (or without the `.min` part), **if** I was on an admin page.

And in your code, you could do like so which would return the proper path if you're on an admin page:

```php
$style_url = apply_filters( 'style_loader_src', $wp_style->src, $wp_style->handle );
```

Or for testing purposes, you could do `wp_style_loader_src( true, 'colors' )`.. before your `foreach`.

Comment: Great. So it's only puprose is to register a stylesheet for a selected admin theme? If yes, it doesn't return the URL, when looping through $wp_styles->registered. Why is that?

Comment: I've updated the post with the code.

Comment:  and does the revised answer help?

Comment: Yes, it does. Thanks. Is there an option to only limit the output the registered values needed for the frontend?

Comment: Maybe, but you can ask that in a separate question - remember, a question should be limited to one question, hence follow-up questions should be posted separately.